# Wordpress get_categories can not find out children directory

Tags: wordpress

I had a wordpress problem which troubled me a lot. I writed a php script that can insert my specific data into the database of wordpress. 
 Actually, I **deleted the initial data of wordpress and used the script to scan my directories to initialize the tables in the database.**

However, I encounterd a problem that I used the **get_categories()** function to find out children directories but failed. Following is my code:

```
   $args = Array('parent'=>'1', 'hide_empty'=>0); 
   echo count(get_categories($args));
```

The fact is that there are some directories in the category with number 1, but it prints 0.
So I used cat_is_ancestor_of function to test:

```
    echo cat_is_ancestor_of(1, 2);
```

It prints 1 which shows that category 2 is children of category 1. I watched the mysql database, category 2 is indeed the son directory of category 1.
But why get_categories returns the wrong answer? It puzzled me a lot! Could anyone help me  solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the child category of a parent category by the following way

```
   <?php
    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=1&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
    echo count($subcategories);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
      echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```